# How to add a column to existing query to show data with different date range values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show [Net Revenue] and [Prior Net Revenue] in the same query. The start and end date ranges are supplied by user. When the query is run, desired output should be:
CustID, CustName, InvoiceDate, NetRevenue, PriorNetRevenue

Note: PriorNetRevenue is for the previous year. So if user enters InvoiceStartDate = '2018-06-30' and InvoiceEndDate = '2019-06-30' then PriorNetRevenue should be from '2017-06-30' and '2018-06-30' for the same customer.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
DECLARE @InvcStartDate datetime = '2018-06-30'
DECLARE @InvcEndDate datetime = '2019-06-30'

SELECT * from 
(SELECT
p.CustID as [Cust ID],
p.CustName as [Cust Name], 
p.InvcDate as [Invoice Date]
SUM(NetRevenue) as [Net Revenue]

FROM ProfitReport p (nolock)
LEFT JOIN Cust_view v (nolock) ON p.CustID = v.CustId
WHERE p.InvcDate BETWEEN @InvcStartDate AND @InvcEndDate
and p.CustType IN ('New','Old')

GROUP BY
p.CustID,
p.CustName, 
p.InvcDate) as c1

INNER JOIN

(SELECT
p.CustID as [Cust ID],
p.CustName as [Cust Name], 
p.InvcDate as [Invoice Date]
SUM(NetRevenue) as [PRIOR Net Revenue]

FROM ProfitReport p (nolock)
LEFT JOIN Cust_view v (nolock) ON p.CustID = v.CustId
WHERE p.InvcDate BETWEEN @InvcStartDate AND @InvcEndDate
and p.CustType IN ('New','Old')

GROUP BY
p.CustID,
p.CustName, 
p.InvcDate) as c2

on c1.[Cust ID] = c2.[Cust ID]
```

The problem is invoice date is different for different years. I also tried using UNION but it just results in data duplication.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving the goal is to use a CTE which calculates the previous years revenue per customer then join this on to your main query.

```
    declare @InvcStartDate date = '2018-06-30', @InvcEndDate date = '2019-06-30';

    declare @ProfitReport table (
    CustId int,
    CustName nvarchar(15),
    InvcDate date,
    NetRevenue float,
    CustType nvarchar(3)
    );

    declare @Cust_View table (
    CustId int
    );

    insert @Cust_View
    values
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4);


    insert @ProfitReport (CustId, CustName, InvcDate, NetRevenue, CustType)
    values
    (1, 'Bob', '2017-07-01', 500.75, 'Old'),
    (2, 'Linda', '2018-02-05', 320.13, 'Old'),
    (1, 'Steve', '2018-07-06', 612.04, 'New'),
    (2, 'Jane', '2019-05-18', 130.00, 'Old');


with previousyear as (  SELECT
    p.CustID as [Cust ID],
    p.CustName as [Cust Name], 
    p.InvcDate as [Invoice Date],
    SUM(NetRevenue) as [Net Revenue]

    FROM @ProfitReport p
    LEFT JOIN @Cust_view v ON p.CustID = v.CustId
    WHERE p.InvcDate BETWEEN dateadd(year, -1, @InvcStartDate) AND dateadd(year, -1, @InvcEndDate)
    and p.CustType IN ('New','Old')

    GROUP BY
    p.CustID,
    p.CustName, 
    p.InvcDate)

    SELECT
    p.CustID as [Cust ID],
    p.CustName as [Cust Name], 
    p.InvcDate as [Invoice Date],
    SUM(p.NetRevenue) as [Net Revenue],
    p2.[Net Revenue] as [Prior Net Revenue]

    FROM @ProfitReport p
    LEFT JOIN @Cust_view v ON p.CustID = v.CustId
    left join previousyear p2 on p.CustId=p2.[Cust ID]
    WHERE p.InvcDate BETWEEN @InvcStartDate AND @InvcEndDate
    and p.CustType IN ('New','Old')

    GROUP BY
    p.CustID,
    p.CustName, 
    p.InvcDate,
    p2.[Net Revenue];
```

[image]

Comment: You're very welcome :) if this answer or any other has helped point you in the right direction then you can show your appreciation with an upvote and/or an accept.